# Powershell get content and Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I want to error messages from all files in a folder and print the only that error messages from each file to a new txt document. This is what i have done so far. I dont know how I should proceed to save the error messeges to a new txt doc.

I want only each row from all log files with that error messages to be saved to the new document. So when you open the new document you only see the error messeges and the path where they come from.

```sh
Get-ChildItem "H:\Script\Log_test" -Filter "*.log" -recurse | Select-String -pattern "error" | group path | select name | Out-File "H:\Script\Log_test\result.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `select` the `Line` property of the `MatchInfo` object returned from the [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet with the `-expand` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem "H:\Script\Log_test" -Filter "*.log" -recurse | 
    Select-String -pattern "error" | 
    select -expand Line | 
    Out-File "H:\Script\Log_test\result.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to filter folder too at the same time i filter files?

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: when i use -Filter  " *.log" can i use this for folders too?

Comment: provide an example, i will try to find an answer